# Small Business Server 2008 without Exchange... how and why?

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I just bought Small Business Server 2008, and then realized... I don't really want to use Exchange locally. I'd prefer to have *hosted* Exchange. Doh.

Is it safe to uninstall Exchange from a SBS2008 installation?

Also, is there even a point to using SBS2008 without exchange, as opposed to using just Server 2008 Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really much point in running SBS without Exchange, but you have spent the money already so you might as well use the license. AFAIK it['s perfectly save to uninstall Exchange, however, I would not waste any time on that. I would simply disable all Exchange related services and get on with whatever else needs doing.

Comment: Surely the built-in "Wizards" and what-not are going to have a fit if you do this.

Comment: I disagree about just disabling the exchange service. Uninstall the application. It will make service packs, on-going maintenance, and even backup/recovery easier on you.

Comment: Thanks wolkfgagsz. Good advice on the "may as well use it" bit, but I'm far too neurotic to knowingly have something that was a stupid purchase. Fortunately, I was able to eBay it for *$50 more* than I paid for it on eBay not a month earlier. Yay for me.

Answer (score 3):

While you can probably uninstall Exchange, you would probably need to keep purchasing SBS CALs, which will work out more expensive than plain Windows Server CALs.

If possible, exchange SBS for a plain Windows Server product if you don't plan on using Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't opened it yet or rather if you can return it, the Windows 2008 Standard will be cheaper.  So if you can return it and get the standard edition you'll save some $$$